# Reverse validation jQuery empty input field

Tags: jquery, validation

So i'm just trying to do define when a value of a input field is empty or null. This would be simple with the [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) function of jQuery. Combine that with reverse validation and you would get this:

```
if($('input').val() != '' || $('input').val() != null)
{
   //any code
}
```

However for some reason this didn't did the trick as it usual does.
Instead i had to use this:

```
if(!$('input').val() == '' || !$('input').val() == null)
{
   //any code
}
```

So i wonder: What is excatly the difference between those two? And why does the first code doesn't work the same as the second code?

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S8ca7/5/)** of the first code, 
**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S8ca7/6/)** of the second code

**Updated:**

Added a selection box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `val()` can't be empty string and `null` at the same time. That's why `if($('input').val() != '' || $('input').val() != null)` will **always** return `true`.

You need `&&` in this case.

Second example is way more interesting. Since JS is not strongly-typed language, `!$('input').val() == ''` tries to compare `!$('input').val()` with empty string, i.e. it casts `$('input').val()` to `bool`, negates it, gets `false` as a result and compares this value with empty string.

The best part of it: `false == ''` equals... `true`! Implicit type conversion did it well.

**What can you do?**

1. In the first example simply change `||` to `&&`:

   ```
   if ($('input').val() != '' && $('input').val() != null)
   ```
2. In the second one you should fix operations order:

   ```
   if (!($('input').val() == '') && !($('input').val() == null))
   ```

   or better

   ```
   if (!($('input').val() == '' || $('input').val() == null))
   ```

Comment: Now i have 1 more questions: You said: "val() can't be empty string **and** null at the same time". I know, that's why i used the OR(`||`) operator instead of the AND(`&&`) operator.

Comment: @nkmol, let's see: 1) `'' != '' || '' != null` -> `false || true` -> `true`; 2) `null != '' || null != null` -> `true || false` -> `true`

Comment: I can't thank you enough for this new subject, it's really interesting! However one step is still unclear for me. Why is `false || true` -> `true` and `false && true` -> `false`? Is this just a rule?

Comment: @nkmol, yes - OR-expression is true if _at least_ on of conditions is true. AND-expression is true only if _both_ conditions are true. You can get some information here - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra_(logic)#Basic_operations

Comment: It's just the same as a OR-gate and AND-gate of an CMA System board :O Been some years ago. Wow, what a eye-opener! Thank you very much mister!